# MySQL - Multi-join with same table and another table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a site and a relative CMS where enabled users can view and edit site pages contents and informations. Each page is associated with a menu voice, through which site users can open and view the page. Pages and menu are stored respectively in pm_sections and pm_menu tables. When a CMS user wants to insert a new page, he must specify the belonging of associated menu voice. There are three levels of belonging:

```
-> menu group (1)
   -> main menu voice (2), inside a menu group
      -> secondary menu voice (3), inside a main menu voice
```

In pm_menu table, informations about belonging are stored in "belonging" column (value: 1, 2 or 3) and "menu_id" column (menu voice belonging ID). There is also another table, pm_menu_groups, which contains main menu groups.

My problem is the following: I have to join sections and menu tables in order to list informations in CMS pages edit page. I've tried to do it with a UNION clause:

```
SELECT s_id, section_name, menu_name, seo_title, last_edit
FROM 
((SELECT s.id AS s_id, s.name AS section_name, s.content AS content, m.belonging AS belonging, m.menu_id AS menu_id, n.name AS menu_name, s.seo_title AS seo_title, s.added_by AS author, s.modify_date AS last_edit FROM pm_sections s, pm_menu m, pm_menu n
WHERE m.section_id = s.id
AND m.link IS NULL
AND m.menu_id = n.id
AND m.belonging = 3)

UNION

(SELECT s.id AS s_id, s.name AS section_name, s.content AS content, m.belonging AS belonging, m.menu_id AS menu_id, n.name AS menu_name, s.seo_title AS seo_title, s.added_by AS author, s.modify_date AS last_edit
FROM pm_sections s, pm_menu m, pm_menu n
WHERE m.section_id = s.id
AND m.link IS NULL
AND m.menu_id = n.id
AND m.belonging = 2)

UNION

(SELECT s.id AS s_id, s.name AS section_name, s.content AS content, m.belonging AS belonging, m.menu_id AS menu_id, g.name AS menu_name, s.seo_title AS seo_title, s.added_by AS author, s.modify_date AS last_edit
FROM pm_sections s, pm_menu m, pm_menu_groups g
WHERE m.section_id = s.id
AND m.link IS NULL
AND m.menu_id = g.id
AND m.belonging = 1))

AS belongings_table
ORDER BY section_name
```

I would ask you if it's possible to do it with a single query...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you outer query the following fields are not used

```
s.added_by AS author, 
s.content AS content, 
m.belonging AS belonging, 
m.menu_id AS menu_id,
```

so I guess they don't need to be included

**differences**

If I read the other three queries correctly the only difference is in the where clause

```
AND m.menu_id = n.id
AND m.belonging = 3
```

or

```
AND m.menu_id = n.id
AND m.belonging = 2
```

or

```
AND m.menu_id = g.id
AND m.belonging = 1
```

**which can be simplified as**

```
AND m.menu_id = n.id
AND m.belonging in (2, 3)
```

or

```
AND m.menu_id = g.id
AND m.belonging = 1
```

**Finally** 
and made into correct sql ( unless I have a type or two )

```
SELECT 
  s.id AS s_id, 
  s.name AS section_name, 
  n.name AS menu_name, 
  s.seo_title AS seo_title, 
  s.modify_date AS last_edit
FROM 
  pm_sections s, 
  pm_menu m, 
  pm_menu n, 
  pm_menu_groups g
WHERE 
  m.section_id = s.id AND 
  m.link IS NULL AND 
  ( 
    ( m.menu_id = n.id AND m.belonging In (2,3) ) or
    ( m.menu_id = g.id AND m.belonging = 1) 
  )
```

Comment: You forgot to add "pm_menu_groups g" in FROM clause ;)
Unfortunately it doesn't work... It joins each page with all pm_menu records :(